# Getting Error while sending post request in flask (python)

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am sending a post request to function which is coroutine but I am getting below error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

Below is function which call after submit button:
and function f() is fetching some data from a get request and return the json from response.

```
    @app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def submit():
       result = yield from f()
       return  render_template('test.html', result=result)


def f()
  response = yield from request('get',...)
  ....
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use coroutines as Flask routes, that's not how Flask, or the WSGI protocol, work. WSGI handles one request/response per thread/process/eventlet. If you need to do background tasks, spawn a thread or use a task queue like Celery.

You *can* return a response containing a generator to [stream the response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/). It will still run synchronously in one thread though.

```
def stream():
    yield 'thing one'
    yield from other_thing()
    yield 'thing two'

return current_app.response_class(stream())
```

If you use gevent, you can [use eventlets instead of threads](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class) to handle each request, in which case you can spawn other eventlets. This comes with it's own performance issues, since all eventlets run in a loop in one thread (this is true of asyncio too). Gunicorn also supports aiohttp, but Flask does not, although it may be possible to get it to work.